# Twig concatenation syntax

Tags: twig

I'm struggling to find the correct Twig concatenation syntax.
Here's what I've got:

```
{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (__SELF__.pageParam): page }) }}
```

it gives the url with the pagination number at the end of the url:

http://sites.local12/category/style/rock/2

Now I want to insert a colon before the pagination number like this:

http://sites.local12/category/style/rock/:2

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got it. I was confused by the "page" filter (I'm new to Twig).

```
{{ this.page.baseFileName|page( {(__SELF__.pageParam): ':' ~ page }) }}
```